# Why can I no longer update my bookdown book?

Tags: bookdown

I am working on a book using rbookdown and a short while ago it stopped generating an up-to-date copy when I knit the index.Rmd file - it continues to generate an older copy. I have made minor edits to every chapter and none are coming through. There are no error messages or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by starting from scratch with the minimal example and copying over all of my chapter files. Hopefully it was an isolated issue.